# How to display a sentence word by word in a TextView?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I tried this code but it only displays the last word:

```
signButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String speech = "This code is sample";
                String[] result = speech.split("\\s");
                for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++) {
                    textView.setText(result[x]);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve here is to read word by word in phrase and display it in one textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first it took me time to just understand your question which I am still unsure, to my understanding you want to show next WORD added in a textView on a button click. . .

To achieve this you can use following code.

```
//String Array preparation
    String speech = "This code is sample";
    String[] result = speech.split("\\s");
    int count = 0;

    signButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   //check if array has more values to add or whatever you want to check
                   if(count<result.length){
                      if(count==0){
                        textView.append(result[count]; 
                      } else {
                        textView.append(" " + result[count];
                      }
                      count++;
                   }                    
                }
            });
```

Comment: This code worked. Thank you !! But is it possible it will display without clicking the button ?

Comment: yes! why not in android you can do anything :)
I answered for button click cause it was in your code.

Comment: use your own FOR loop code just replace setText() with append()   and it will do the trick if yes do upvote :P

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it to 
declare globally a string var

```
String s="";
```

Now use this s in your code 
Inside the for loop

```
s=s+""+result[x];
textView.append(s):
```

Answer (score 0):

The textview will displays only the last word since it is in a for loop. After setting each word the next iteration will happens and so, user can view only the last word. You can change each word after a particular time. Try the below code. In this I have given 5 seconds for showing each word.

```
int x; //declare x as global variable

String speech = "This code is sample";
String[] result = speech.split("\\s");
textView.setText(result[0]);

for (x=1; x<result.length; x++) {
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
           textView.setText(result[x]);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Error:(43, 53) error: local variable x is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

Comment: I have edited the answer. x should be declared as global variable.